# How to reverse the effect of text alignment when browser is larger

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

On really small devices I want to align the title text on the screen.
So I added the text-align and vertical-align.

Now when the browser is larger, I want to remove these 2 css properties.

How can I do that?

```
.main-title {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

  @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
    text-align: inherit;
    vertical-align: inherit;
  }
}
```

Comment: text-align:initial -> sets to default value and text-align:inherit -> takes alignment from parent. Can you try with text-align:initial ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries only for small devices.
For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-title{
    text-align: inherit;
    vertical-align: inherit; 
  }
}
```